# Custom search in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables-1.10

I am using jquery datatable and creating custom search functionality like following.

**HTML Code:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtFirstName" /></td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtLastName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>From Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtFromDate" /></td>
    <td>To Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtToDate" /></td>        
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtAddress" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" /></td>   
</tr>
 </table>
 <table id="mytable">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Birth Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  </table>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#txtFromDate, #txtToDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd MM yy' });

    var MyDataTable = $("#mytable").dataTable(
        {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":
          {
              "url": "/Home/GetData",
              "type": "POST",
              "dataType": "JSON",
              //"contentType": "JSON",
              "data": {
                  "FirstName": $("#txtFirstName").val().trim(),
                  "LastName": $("#txtLastName").val().trim(),
                  "Address": $("#txtAddress").val().trim(),
                  "FromDate": $("#txtFromDate").val(),
                  "ToDate": $("#txtToDate").val()
              }
          },
            columns: [
            { data: 'FirstName' },
            { data: 'LastName' },
            { data: 'Address' },
            {
                data: 'DOB',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    var rawdate = data.substr(6);
                    var dt = new Date(parseFloat(rawdate));
                    return $.format.date(dt, "dd MMM yyyy");
                }
            }
            ]
        });

    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        //1. draw it's not working
        //MyDataTable.draw();
        //2. ajax.reload it's not working
        //MyDataTable.ajax.reload(null, true);
    });
});
```

**My code at server-side**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetData(MyViewModel info)
    {
      ............
    }
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel: DTParameters
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is when I first time load page it goes to controller action method GetData and my model MyViewModel get null values which is right. When I enter some search criteria ie. first name, last name and hit search button I want to pass entered value to server-side but I am getting null values. For passing values to server-side I tried to reload datatable using dataTable().draw() method and dataTable().ajax.reload() method but it's not working. What is wrong in code. Thanks in advance....

Comment: I am unsure about what you have for your server-side code but I believe with DataTables it should initially load all of the rows, and when you type something in the search it actually filters the results to show you fewer rows.

Comment: If you press enter will get value in controller on second time?

Comment: @HackbalTeamz When I press enter button I get null values in controller.

Comment: @Alesana I am trying to implement custom search functionality. In built-in functionality yes there is auto filters.

Comment: @LoneWolf Can you send MyViewModel Detail also

Comment: @HackbalTeamz updated. MyViewModel.cs file contains search fields along with other parameters which are used for datatable.

Comment: @LoneWolf var postData = { favorite: favorite, category: category }; Try like this

Comment: As far I know datatable send some other information to the server while search. You may follow [datatable server side implementation](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my question. I just modify "ajax" part to like this

```
"ajax":
      {
          "url": "/Home/GetData",
          "type": "POST",
          "dataType": "JSON",
          //"contentType": "JSON",
          "data": function ( d ) {
                    return $.extend( {}, d, {
                      "FirstName": $("#txtFirstName").val().trim(),
                      "LastName": $("#txtLastName").val().trim(),
                      "Address": $("#txtAddress").val().trim(),
                      "FromDate": $("#txtFromDate").val(),
                      "ToDate": $("#txtToDate").val()
                    });
          }
      },
```

and also on button clicked I used following code:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    $("#mytable").DataTable().draw();
});
```